# javascript XMLHttpRequest requestXML is null

Tags: javascript, null, xmlhttprequest, response

I'm trying to grab an xml document from a url and then parse it.  I am able to open it fine on a browser, but it doesnt seem to work through my javascript.  Can anyone help me?

```
function downloadUrl(url, callback) {       
     var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
         new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
         new XMLHttpRequest;

     request.onreadystatechange = function() {
       if (request.readyState == 4) {
         request.onreadystatechange = function(){};
         callback(request, request.status);
       }
     };

    request.open('GET', "url", true);       
    request.send(null);
}   
downloadUrl("http://jojo.theone.net/survey.xml", function(data) {   
    alert("Inside downloadURL"); // shows up            
    var xml = request.responseXML;
    alert(xml);  // Doesn't even show up.
        alert(request.responseText); // Doesnt show up.


});
```

Comment: Is the script running on  `jojo.theone.net`?

Answer (score 2):

You are using `data` as the parameter name in your callback method, but calling the callback method as `callback(request, request.status)`.  The result is that the request object is now in the var called "data", and the request.status is not referenced at all.

Try

```
downloadUrl("http://jojo.theone.net/survey.xml", function(request, status) {   
    alert("Inside downloadURL");
    var xml = request.responseXML;
    alert(xml); 
    alert(request.responseText);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `data` value not the `request` object. Also it is better to use some framework like Mootools or jQuery to perform AJAX requests -- you'll get a more compatible and predictable interface.
Also note that request will fail if the url you're requesting has different server, port and protocol than the script that is making request.

Comment: The url does have a different port than the script.  Is there any way around this?

Comment: No -- this would be considered as a serious security hole, so no browser will do this. You must make a router on the server side and settle some url that will be rewritten to a different port by it.